# giving link to a word inside <p> tag

Tags: html, hyperlink, web, tags

I'm trying to give link inside p tag and all word order collapse any way to do it.Here my code below;
Normal Code
[image]

Result
[image]

I need to link just a word.
[image]

after I insert link inside p tag result;
[image]

Comment: You should add you code instead of its snap shot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspect link tag and check CSS properties for why link align right.

or

Override CSS proprties for `a` tag.

Comment: I check css rules and cant find anything like right alligned. As you mention override how can I do that.

Comment: you can do this in multiple way for example

`<p style="text-align: right;"> some text <a href="http://link">Link here</a> some text </p>`